# Trying to access an object in a class extended from another class

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I'm Trying to access an object in a class extended from another class. But I'm getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object".

This is the code: http://3v4l.org/ZLTWf#v500

why can i not access the `$doo->var_2->var`? i works fine with `$foo->var_2->var` (as it should) but why do i get an error when i extend the class? Is it allowed in PHP? Is there some extra code that will allow me to do that?

I'm even getting an "Undefined variable" error on `$doo->$var_3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here

```
class TheClass extends SecondClass{
    public $var_3;
    function __construct(){
        $this->var_3 = "Some Text...";
    }
}
```

You have overwritten the parent constructor so when you instantiate the class the constructor of its parent will not be called since its overwritten.

You can fix it as

```
class TheClass extends SecondClass{
    public $var_3;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->var_3 = "Some Text...";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope I get the result as texttext

Comment: For me this solution works fine. You erase the initialize of MainClass(). So var_2 was NULL

Comment: <troll>@Ameer Stop create bug </troll>. `$doo->$var_3` to `$doo->var_3`.

Comment: @Debflav sorry it was my bad.